# How to write the following sequence

Tags: math-mode

Could you please help me to write the latex code of the following pic.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you show how far you've got with your own attempt by adding a small compilable document of what you've tried.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a "do it for me" site.

Comment: Can you explain why the diagram contains only `-` (minus) symbols but no `+` (plus) symbols?

Comment: @Mico This is bijection for Catalan numbers with the sequence of the numbers $\pm 1$. I abstinence to write $+1$. We can use $+$ symbols also.

Comment: @PeterWilson I just do not know the notation \underbrace.

Comment: @d.y Underbrace is a basic part of LaTeX. Read the manual  Leslie Lamport "Latex User's Guide and Reference Manual" section 3.3.6 . Why didn't you check before exposing your ignorance? -- GOM

Answer (score 5):

I should probably not answer the question in its current formulation. Please keem Alan Munn's and Peter Wilson's advice in your head for your next question. You are not new to this site, so please stick to the rules.

I'll give you a starting point, I am sure you are able to complete it on your own.
[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \underbrace{
            \underbrace{
                \underbrace{
                    \underbrace{
                    1}_1
                1}_2
            1}_3
        -1}_2
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution for the full diagram.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\underbrace' macro
\let\ub\underbrace   % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % optional
\begin{document}
$\ub{\ub{\ub{\ub{\ub{\ub{\ub{\ub{1}_1 1}_2 1}_3 -1}_2 1}_3 -1}_2 -1}_1 -1}_0$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* Speaking for myself, I think the diagram would look a lot better if the top row contained not only `-` (minus) symbols but also `+` (plus) symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\underbrace' macro
\let\ub\underbrace   % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % optional
\begin{document}
$\ub{{\ub{{\ub{{\ub{{\ub{{\ub{{\ub{{\ub{1}_1} +1}_2} +1}_3} -1}_2} +1}_3} -1}_2} -1}_1} -1}_0$
\end{document}
```